# Mongoose count function to get index number of documents

Tags: mongodb, indexing, count, mongoose, database-schema

I am writing an app that stores documents in a MongoDB database. I want to have an index number associated with each document that gets automatically generated.

I'm trying to count the number of documents currently in the database and set the index number to that. So how do I use the Mongoose.js count function to achieve this? Or is there a better way to do it?

This is my document.js file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var DocSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Title: String,
    Date: Date,
    Author: String,
});

mongoose.model('Doc', DocSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to also add an `index` field to the Schema for this to work.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var DocModel = mongoose.model('Doc');

var newDoc = new DocModel();
newDoc.Title = 'Title of Book';
newDoc.Date = new Date();
newDoc.Author = 'Author Name';'

DocModel.count().exec(function(err, count){
    newDoc.index = count;
    newDoc.save(function(err, result){
       if(err){
           console.log('Error saving new document');
           console.log(err);
           return;
       }
       console.log('New document created successfully!);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please see the edit and show how to add your code into this! @Matthew Antolovich

Comment: @axc Are you trying to make the index be set at the Schema level?

Comment: Yes exactly at the index level @Matthew Antolovich

Comment: @OneMoreQuestion There are several different methods as to how to do it.  Can you post your Schema so I can tailor the answer for your code?  Also, keep in mind that if you delete a document from the collection, and then create a new document, the index field of the new document will be the same value as the index of the 2nd newest document.

Do you want the Index value to always be unique?  I can make it so the index for the new document is one number higher that the highest index field in the collection, but if you delete documents, the there may be missing documents for certain indices.

Comment: @OneMoreQuestion If you have 100 documents, with index values ranging from 0-100, and you delete the document at index 77, then you will no longer have a document with the index of 77.  It is possible to update the index values of all documents to account for this, but it will have to update every document with an index greater than the one deleted.  Depending on how large your collection gets and how often documents are removed, this could impact performance.